# Python scipy: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'list'

Tags: python, scipy

I need to fit function to array of data and get optimal coefficients of an equation of this function. I use **curve_fit** method from scipy library. It is based on least squares method.

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

#This is my function from which i need to get optimal coefficients 'a' and 'b'
def func(x, a, b):  
return a*x**(b*x)

#the arrays of input data                               
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y =[6,7,8,9,10]

#default (guess) coefficients
p0 = [1, 1] 

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y, p0)
print popt
```

It returns the following error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'list'

But when I use the other, more simple function with no power operation it works

```
def func(x, a, b):  
return a*x + b
```

It must be trying to bulid number to a power of an entire array of input data

What to do? Help please...

Comment: How exactly would you put an array to the power of another array?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like you're after element-wise power-raising?

Like `a*x[i]**(b*x[i])` for each i?

In that case, you have to use the [`np.power`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.power.html) function:

```
def func(x,a,b):
    return a*np.power(x,b*x)
```

Then it works.

(As an aside, it may be worthwhile to convert `x` and `y` from lists to numpy arrays: `np.array(x)`).

Comment: I have tried with this:
def f(x):
    return 1 / (x ** 5 * (np.power(np.exp, 1/x)))
, but not worked for me.