# scipy.optimize.curve_fit, TypeError: unsupported operand type

Tags: python, scipy, typeerror, curve-fitting

I've done a search and the problem seems similar to [Python scipy: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156208/python-scipy-unsupported-operand-types-for-or-pow-list-and-list)
however the solution posted there did not work and I think it may actually be different.

I am trying to fit a curve to data using scipy.curve_fit, when I leave all 3 parameters free everything works correctly and I get the expected result.

```
def func(x,a,b,c):
  return a*np.exp(b*(x**c)) 

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func,x,y)
```

However when I try to fix one of the values (c=2) as below,

```
def func2(x,a,b):
  return a*np.exp(b*(x**2))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func2,x,y)
```

I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'int' and 'list'` using `numpy.power(x,2)` as suggested in the linked question allows the code to run but produces the wrong result. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Edited to add:
Even more confusingly leastsq, which as far I know is used by curve_fit, with the 2nd formula works.

2nd Edit:
To those to mentioned the list problems X and Y are now both arrays and the code runs without error. However func2 still produces drastically the wrong result. (I would post the graph here but apparently I need more rep.)

Func 1 curvefit gives `[a,b,c] =  [ 1.71890826, -0.0239123,   3.17039851]` however for func2 it all goes wrong `[a,b] = [ -2.88694423e-15,   9.99999998e-01]`. I don't understand how such a small change can be causing such a drastic problem, leastsq was able to fit this data with c=2.

Comment: Can you provide an example of `x` and `y`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `TypeError` occurs because the `x` being passed to `func2` is a list.

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as optimize
def func2(x,a,b):
    return a*np.exp(b*(x**2))

x = np.linspace(0,1,6).reshape(2,-1)
y = func2(x,1,1)
x = x.tolist()
y = y.tolist()
print(x)
# [[0.0, 0.2, 0.4], [0.6000000000000001, 0.8, 1.0]]
print(y)
# [[1.0, 1.0408107741923882, 1.1735108709918103], [1.4333294145603404, 1.8964808793049517, 2.718281828459045]]

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(func2, x, y)
# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'
```

In this case, `func2` maps an array `x` of shape (2,3) to an array `y` of shape (2,3). The function `optimize.curve_fit` expects the return value from `func2` to be a sequence of numbers -- not an array.

Fortunately for us, in this case, `func2` is operating element-wise on each component of `x` -- there is no interaction between the elements of `x`. So it really makes no difference if we pass an array `x` of shape (2,3) or an 1D array of shape (6,).

If we pass an array of shape (6,) then `func2` will return an array of shape (6,). Perfect. That's will do just fine:

```
x = np.asarray(x).ravel()
y = np.asarray(y).ravel()
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(func2, x, y)
print(popt)
# [ 1.  1.]
```

Comment: X and y were indeed lists, have converted to arrays and am running again (it'll take a while). Hopefully that will work, what I don't understand is why the first example worked but the 2nd failed. Surely if the data being a list is the issue they both should have failed?

Comment: We have two different things here which are both being called `x`. There is the `x` that is being passed as an argument to `optimize.curve_fit`, and the `x` being passed to `func2`. The former (I am guessing) was a list of lists. In that case, the latter would be a list of numbers. (Each item in the former `x` gets passed to `func2` one at a time). `func2` raises a TypeError when the latter `x` is a list.

Comment: The code now runs once X and Y were converted to arrays, however func2 does not produce the correct result, both functions were given identical data and I know leastsq is able to fit the data when C=2. I am completely stuck with this.

Comment: `leastsq` requires you to pass an initial guess for the parameters. Are you passing the same guess to `curve_fit`?

Comment: Ahh, well now I feel stupid, no I was not providing an initial case in the curve_fit case whereas I was with leastsq. If seems in the c=? it was able to get there from a start of 1 but was divergent in the c=2 case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What `x` values did you use? Following example works for me.

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

def func2(x,a,b):
  return a*np.exp(b*(x**2))

x = np.linspace(0,4,50)
y = func2(x, 2.5, 2.3)
yn = y + 6.*np.random.normal(size=len(x))
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func2,x,yn)
print popt, pcov
```

It gives the result depending on the `random` function:

```
[ 1.64182333  2.00134505] [[  1.77331612e+11  -6.77171181e+09]
 [ -6.77171181e+09   2.58627411e+08]]
```

Are your `x` and `yn` values of type list? Following example gives your error message:

```
print range(10)**2

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: X and y were indeed lists, have converted to arrays and am running again (it'll take a while). Hopefully that will work, what I don't understand is why the first example worked but the 2nd failed. Surely if the data being a list is the issue they both should have failed?

Answer (score 0):

Python is trying to do something like this:

```
[1, 2, 3] * 4
```

for which the * operator is not defined in CPython.

This worked for me:

```
def second_order_polynomial(x, a, b, c):
    return [a * x0**2 + b * x0 + c for x0 in x]
```