# Unsupported Operand Type Error with scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` to fit a model function, but the following code gives me the following error:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from math import log10

def my_func(x, alpha):
return [10*log10(alpha*y*y) for y in x]

known_x = [1039.885254, 2256.833008, 6428.667969, 30602.62891] #known x-values
known_y = [31.87999916, 33.63000107, 35, 36.74000168]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(my_func, known_x, known_y)
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
```

I know related questions have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284918/scipy-optimize-curve-fit-typeerror-unsupported-operand-type) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156208/python-scipy-unsupported-operand-types-for-or-pow-list-and-list) but I wasn't able to solve my problem from those answers.

I did double check the type of of the arguments that `curve_fit` sends to my function and I saw that `alpha` comes in as `numpy.float64` and `x` as `list`

Thanks for your help.

Here is the traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(my_func, known_x, known_y)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 506, in curve_fit
    res = leastsq(func, p0, args=args, full_output=1, **kw)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 348, in leastsq
    m = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)[0]
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 14, in _check_func
    res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 418, in _general_function
    return function(xdata, *params) - ydata
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
```

Here is `_general_function`:

```
def _general_function(params, xdata, ydata, function):
    return function(xdata, *params) - ydata
```

Comment: I think the error is in the method `curve_fit`. Include it's source

Comment: Here is the function where the error is: `def _general_function(params, xdata, ydata, function):
    return function(xdata, *params) - ydata`. It is redirected by curve_fit

Comment: Added the traceback :)

Comment: Simply, `list` can't be subtracted by another `list`, in order to do so, they should be in `numpy.array`. (Alright, as long as as one of them is), but let's just get all of them in `np.array` for consistency.

Comment: This has been fixed in the development version of scipy.  The fix will be in the soon-to-be-released version 0.14.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to convert you `list`s to `np.array`:

```
def my_func(x, alpha):
    return np.array([10*np.log10(alpha*y*y) for y in x])

known_x = np.array([1039.885254, 2256.833008, 6428.667969, 30602.62891]) #known x-values
known_y = np.array([31.87999916, 33.63000107, 35, 36.74000168])
```

Result:

```
(array([ 0.00012562]), array([[  2.38452809e-08]]))
```

The reason is quite evident as indicated by this message:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'`

Sure, `list` can not be subtracted by a `list`. In order to do so, we need them to be in `numpy.array`